# Brawler and two weapon fighting feat tree

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

One of my players is a [brawler](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/brawler). He just reached level 8 and got improved two weapon fighting. He asked what his attacks were suppose to be and I went to tell him, only to find out that I didnt know what the feat was getting at exactly.

So at level 8 the brawlers bab is 8/3.

When using [twf](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/two-weapon-fighting-combat---final) it becomes 6/6/1 (using light weapons)

When using [itwf](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-two-weapon-fighting-combat---final) it becomes 6/6/1/1 (using light weapons)?

When he reaches 15th level bab is 15/10/5, or 13/13/8/3 with twf, or 13/13/8/8/3 with itwf, so with [gtwf](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-two-weapon-fighting-combat---final) its 13/13/8/8/3/3?

Two weapon fighting had such a helpful table for figuring this out.

Comment: Everything you have listed is correct. What is the question? Is that all you wanted to know?

Comment: So my calculations are actually right? I was second guessing myself over what their intent was that I just didnt know. I was expecting a progression more like the monks, which is more staggered for values.

Comment: Monk BAB increases at a rate of 3/4 a level, Brawler increases at a rate of 1 a level. That's why you are seeing a different progression. Compare something like Fighter and Cleric as well.

Comment: What gets me is that every offhand attack with the light weapon will have the same value as the primary.

Comment: That's how two weapon fighting has always worked in Pathfinder. Both hands take a -2 penalty on attacks with light weapons, if you have the feat, but otherwise ignore the penalties for dual wielding without the feat. ITWF and GTWF just add an iterative attack for your offhand weapon.

Comment: @KRyan I feel a bit like a thief for answering...

Comment: @gatherer818 eh, I had many chances to, and I hardly need the rep. No worries. This is part of why you don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So at level 8 the brawlers bab is 8/3.

When using twf it becomes 6/6/1 (using light weapons)

When using itwf it becomes 6/6/1/1 (using light weapons)

You are exactly right.  Two Weapon Fighting reduces the off-hand penalty to zero and reduces the penalty to each hand to -2 (when using a light weapon in the off-hand), and Improved Two Weapon Fighting just adds an iterative at an additional -5 to the off-hand, so this is correct.  (Way back in DnD 3.0, you needed both Two Weapon Fighting and Ambidexterity to get this full benefit.  Ambidexterity was rolled into TWF since.)